# How to call a fragment-class from inside another fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

In my project I have a fragment view `(as the layout of a sliding menu)` which is attached to my MainActivity. Inside my menu-fragment, I have another fragment *(inner fragment)* which calls a class from the XML itself like this:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/innerfragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="175dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    class="com.myproject.android.fragment.MyInnerFragment" />
```

When I run the project, it is showing the following `java.lang.RuntimeException`

```
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #76: Error inflating class fragment
```

***Q: How can I call the inner fragment class, from XML or code?***

This same `XML` was working when it was set under an activity before the sliding menu was introduced.

**`EDIT:`**

To make it clear, this it how the layout looks like. The sliding menu view is a RelativeLayout named menu.xml

[image]

The inner-fragment content varies according options selected in the MainActivity.

Comment: `class="com.myproject.android.fragment$MyInnerFragment"` <= `$` sign for inner class

Comment: @Selvin I tried this code out. But I got `android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.utm.android.fragment$MyInnerFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public`. The class is public and also has an empty constructor. :( +1 for trying.. :)

Comment: is inner class static ? if no, than this could be the problem ... (and yes, if you change inner class to static you can't access to outer class whithout it reference)

Comment: No. The inner fragment content varies each time a change is made in the activity from which the sliding menu is extended. I have added an image to make it more clear.

Comment: have yuou seen NestedFragment Sample...??

Comment: @SalmanKhan Yea. I have looked into it.. But I think I found the problem. Just see my answer. I made it working in this way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found out the solution to my question.

First of all I was using the wrong android support jar for my project *(Maven Project)*. **;)**

I fixed that with the `latest android support jar` file and the second issue was probably that **my inner fragment was getting set up before the outer view was created.**

Anyways, I inserted this code into my outer fragment and it started working all fine..!

```
@AfterInject
public void setupfragment()
{
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
      myinnerFragment = new PresetsFragment_();
      fragmentTransaction.add( R.id.menu_my_frame, myinnerFragment );
      fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Better answers are always welcome. Until then I am marking this answer as the correct one..! **;)**

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mention that I removed my code from the XML and implemented it from the code inside my outer fragment. **:D**

Comment: @SalmanKhan Thanks, but I wonder if there are better answers..! **;)**